# Sending Serialnumber/IMEI to phone via SMS using SIM900A and arduino uno

Tags: arduino

I am trying to send IMEI number of GSM device to phone via SMS. How should I do it?

after AT+CMGF=1(text mode), I am writing my number AT+CMGS="+91xxxxxxxxxx"\r" and then I am sending IMEI number with the help of AT+GSNcommand. But it is taking this as string and I am getting AT+GSN as massage because I set it to text mode. Can anyone help in which way it should take it as command so that I can get the value of IMEI number as message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First query your IMEI number, then switch to text mode and send that as a message. Query Imei: `AT+GSN`, switch to text mode: `AT+CMGF=1`, enter your number `AT+CMGS=\"+91xxxxxxxxxx\` and finally paste the acquired imei here closed with a (char)26 (`CTRL+Z`) to send the sms.

You can read the IMEI with command:

```
mySerial.println("AT+GSN");
```

and waiting for the reply:

```
String imei = "";
while(mySerial.available())
    imei = mySerial.readString();
```

and here you can proceed with the sending part.